# Trouble with enabling clojure-mode-extra-font-locking mode in emacs

Tags: emacs, clojure

I am currently trying to enable [clojure-mode-extra-font-locking](https://github.com/clojure-emacs/clojure-mode/blob/master/clojure-mode-extra-font-locking.el) in emacs. Currently it's in

> ~/.emacs.d/bootleg/clojure-mode-extra-font-locking/clojure-mode-extra-font-locking.el

.

I have the following code:

```
(require 'clojure-mode)
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/bootleg/clojure-mode-extra-font-locking/")
(require 'clojure-mode-extra-font-locking)
```

But when I open a .clj file I get this in the minibuffer:

> File mode specification error: (void-function enable)

What am I doing wrong? Thank you!

edit:
This is what I get with

> M-x toggle-debug-on-error

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-function enable)
  enable()
  run-hooks(change-major-mode-after-body-hook prog-mode-hook clojure-mode-hook)
  apply(run-hooks (change-major-mode-after-body-hook prog-mode-hook clojure-mode-hook))
  run-mode-hooks(clojure-mode-hook)
  clojure-mode()
  set-auto-mode-0(clojure-mode nil)
  set-auto-mode()
  normal-mode(t)
  after-find-file(nil t)
  find-file-noselect-1(#<buffer test.clj> "~/src/clojure/test.clj" nil nil "~/src/clojure/test.clj" (16260320 2069))
  find-file-noselect("/home/n/src/clojure/test.clj" nil nil nil)
  find-file("/home/n/src/clojure/test.clj")
  #[257 "\304\305!!r\306\307\310\311\312\313!\314\"\315\316%DC\216\317@\320\"\210   \205$\321\n!?\205)\322\323\n\"!+\207" [ivy-last counsel-find-file-speedup-remote ivy--directory find-file-hook internal--before-with-selected-window ivy--get-window funcall make-byte-code 0 "\301\300!\207" vconcat vector [internal--after-with-selected-window] 2 "\n\n(fn)" select-window norecord file-remote-p find-file expand-file-name] 9 "\n\n(fn X)"]("/home/k/src/clojure/test.clj")
  ivy-call()
  ivy-read("Find file: " read-file-name-internal :matcher counsel--find-file-matcher :initial-input nil :action #[257 "\304\305!!r\306\307\310\311\312\313!\314\"\315\316%DC\216\317@\320\"\210 \205$\321\n!?\205)\322\323\n\"!+\207" [ivy-last counsel-find-file-speedup-remote ivy--directory find-file-hook internal--before-with-selected-window ivy--get-window funcall make-byte-code 0 "\301\300!\207" vconcat vector [internal--after-with-selected-window] 2 "\n\n(fn)" select-window norecord file-remote-p find-file expand-file-name] 9 "\n\n(fn X)"] :preselect nil :require-match confirm-after-completion :history file-name-history :keymap (keymap (C-backspace . counsel-up-directory) (67108991 . counsel-up-directory)) :caller counsel-find-file)
  counsel-find-file()
  call-interactively(counsel-find-file nil nil)
  command-execute(counsel-find-file)
```

Comment: I'd guess it's in one of your hook functions (`change-major-mode-after-body-hook`, `prog-mode-hook`, or `clojure-mode-hook`).  Check all of them and make sure each function in the hooks is working properly.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you really need/want this package?

When I saw your question, my first response was going to be "Don't bother with
it." This was mainly because the last time I looked, the package was fairly out
of date and a while ago, cider had added functionality to provide enhanced
font-locking anyway. However, I then checked and saw that the extra font lock
package has recently been updated and remembered that while cider is fantastic,
there are some who prefer to use inf-clojure rather than cider (especially in
some node based environments where you don't have an nRepl and don't want to go
the piggieback middleware route to fake one).

the first thing you should do is change your setup to get clojure-mode and
clojure-mode-extra-font-lock from the MELPA archive. The clojure-mode and cider
packages are fast moving targets with new packages released pretty much every
week. This is great, but it does make keeping additional packages like the extra
font lock package in sync a little harder. Getting them from the package
archives will likely help ensure things are all in sync.

If your new to clojure, I really wouldn't worry about the additional
font-locking stuff. Far better to concentrate on just clojure-mode, cider and
clj-refactor. IMO these are the much more important parts and the ones which
will enhance the environment and your workflow. Once you have those packages all
working well and your comfortable with them, then go back and look at adding the
extra font locking. There is a high chance you will find it unnecessary.

I also highly recommend using the use-package package to manage your elpa
packages. It makes your init file easier to maintain and can dramatically speed
up emacs startup time.

Comment: I'm also getting the same error when I try to enable paredit or rainbow-delimiters in cider-repl.

Comment: Either show your init or put it somewhere and post the link. Paredit and rainbow-delimiters are common setups for both clojure-mode and cider, so we know they work. Therefore, must be a problem in your init file.